# How turn a excel file into a html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to turn a excel table into a html table, my code so far it's like that, but nothing happens

```
getFile(event) {
let reader = event.target.files;
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var data = new Uint8Array(reader);
  var wb = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
  var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb, { sheet: "sheet no1", type: 'binary', bookType: 'html' });
  $('#table').innerHTML += htmlstr;
}
```

Comment: What does the console say? I imagine you get errors.

Comment: I have that error: reader.readAsArrayBuffer is not a function

Comment: Have you loaded all the code necessary for this to work? These are not native Javascript functions.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why doesn't work